# Value variance when using multiple inner joins

Tags: sql

Working on some sql. I have just one question in mind and if more details are needed, please let me know.

When executing the sql query:

```
select o.prodid, p.prodname, sum(o.qtysold) as "TOTAL SALES"
from orderline o
inner join product p
on o.prodid = p.prodid
group by o.prodid, p.prodname
order by 3;
```

I get the following data:

```
PRODID   PRODNAME    TOTAL SALES
39  Coffee Table    1
33  Large Desk  1
34  Hallway Table   2
37  Zzz King Size Single Bed    2
38  Bedside Lamp    4
31  Lounge Chair    5
36  Lamp Stand (Tall)   7
35  Kitchen Stool   17
```

These results accurately reflect the real values located within the table orderline.

However, when I execute this query:

```
select o.prodid, p.prodname, sum(o.qtysold) as "TOTAL SALES"
from orderline o
inner join product p
on o.prodid = p.prodid
inner join allocation a
on a.prodid = p.prodid
inner join qualitycheck q
on q.prodid = a.prodid
having avg(q.score) >= 2
group by o.prodid, p.prodname
order by 3;
```

I get the following data:

```
PRODID   PRODNAME    TOTAL SALES
33  Large Desk  3
31  Lounge Chair    15
```

The results are accurate in the respect that, the right products have been returned but the data is wrong because the qty sold has been tripled for reasons that I simply do not understand. Any help and explanations as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Reubs

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the group by and run the query without the aggregates, you will see why.

```
select o.prodid, p.prodname, o.qtysold, q.score
from orderline o
   join product p
      on o.prodid = p.prodid
    join allocation a
      on a.prodid = p.prodid
    join qualitycheck q
      on q.prodid = a.prodid
order by 3;
```

The joins to the two new tables have produced a Cartesian product and tripled the number of rows.  The join conditions for one of the two new joins needs another predicate to be added to eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, Charles. The reason why I was using the group by function is because I wanted to return the sum of the sales unique to each proid i.e. sum(o.qtysold). I'm very new to SQL and running this function will not work unless there is a group by clause? Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, you need a group by to execute any aggregate function (like Sum(), AVg(), etc.)  but when you join two tables, every row in the first tabloe is "joined" to every row in the other table, restricted only by the join conditions (the `On` clause).  If there are 3 rows in one table and 5 rows in the other, the result will have 15 rows unless the `on` clause restricts some of them.